# javascript patterns on java enterprise application

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, requirejs

I just wanna ask what are the guidelines on writing javascript files on large java enterprise applications. 
Basically what we do now is replicate the folder structure of the JSPs, 
and every JSP there is a corresponding js file. as you can see below:

```
war
|- js
    |- jquery.js
    |- jquery.ui.js
    |- datatables.js
    |- other-lib.js
    |- pages
        |- login.js
        |- dashboard.js
        |- userAdmin.js
```

We are using [Sitemesh](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh/Home), that's why on the main decorator JSP, all libraries are imported on the `<script>` tag. So on the main decorator JSP you can see something like this:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datatables.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/xform.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/generic.js"></script>
</head>
```

And as I said, the js files under the 'js/pages' folder is imported on their specific JSP file.

Now, I just read [Addy Osmani's Article about JS Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/), and started using the revealing module pattern. but still, I am kind of lost. I came accross this RequireJS framework/tool. But I have no idea on how to start overhauling the js files of the java app.

Where should I put `$(document).ready(function(){})` if I started using module-pattern?

Should I make every JSP page a module? or should I break it down on behavior and create modules depending on the usability/behavior of a concept?

I don't know what else to ask, I have so much in my mind, I usually code back-end since I am a java developer, but now, since there is no front-end engineers on my team, I have to learn this new stuff. Bear with me for I have limited knowledge on javascript and jQuery.

Comment: You have asked about 5 different questions. Which one should we single out for an answer?

Comment: "Where should I put $(document).ready(function(){}) if I started using module-pattern?" I think this question is my priority.
Also, is it okay if you answer the other questions, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to develop complex JS functionality in each of your JSP page, consider putting more focus on structuring the functionality in to modules and in to UI components. As bokonic correctly said, AMD library can help you to put a good structure to your codebase.

If you need to have a look at a reference architecture on building a large scale JavaScript application, have a look at BoilerplateJS ( http://boilerplatejs.org ). It is not a utility library, but an integration of some leading utility libraries in to a reference architecture that can be used as a starting point for a complex JS project.

Even if you do not want to use it as it is, have a look a the concerns being discussed on the homepage. You will be able to get an idea of the necessary architectural approaches for large scale JS projects such as:

- How you should organize the code structure
- How to create a hierarchy of functional modules
- How to make UI components self contained
- How to do routing, bookmarking, history handling
- How to manage JS scripts and dependencies
- How to optimize, obfuscate for deployment
- How to make your components unit testable
- How to deal with styling, localization aspects

I'm the main author of BoilerplateJS and I wrote it to share my experience after doing couple of complex JS projects.

Comment: Hi,boilerplate.js looks really interesting, since i use backbone and backbone.marionette in my projects, i will be grateful if you can provide some example, or point me to example, combining boilerplate.js and backbone. thanks

Comment: Hi I know someone using BoilerplateJS with Backbone. I will get a sample soon and let you know.

Comment: On BoilerplateJS, Now we have added a sample component that uses BackboneJS for MVC. Have a look at the sample TODO component at http://boilerplatejs.org/samples/productsuite/index.html#todo . You can find the code committed on GitHub. In your product you are unlikely to use both backbonejs and knockoutjs, so pick the one you like most ..

Comment: Thanks! i'm sure it will help people using backbone to get started with BoilerplateJS more easily

Answer (score 0):

Using asynchronous modules (AMD, like require.js) can make your js seem a little more like java in that you can have clearly defined namespaces that you can "import" (require) between each other. You'll have the equivalent of a mainline (your main js) that instantiates some top-level object(s).

In JSP or PHP, you'll often add a series of scripts to an HTML document by just echoing `<script>` tags onto the page. With require.js, you'd have to generate javascript customized for that application -- i.e. your main.js will probably be different, or you'll need a script inline.

This makes require.js really great for one-page web apps where you have a ton of javascript and little server-side preprocessing of the template.

It seems that people in the js community (if there is a coherent one) like the revealing module pattern as a way of encapsulating code. It's basically the only good way to get around javascript's scope mess. In addition to that, you can also:

- Factor out common code (modals, site-specific validation, REST api calls, etc) into modules that you can include in every page and ask the user to cache for a longer time
- Write small modules that cover individual pieces of functionality. This way you can swap them out or include them on different pages as it becomes necessary.
- Consider using a js build tool like [grunt](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt), which will concatenate and minify your javascript. [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/build/) also has a good one.

In the revealing-module pattern you don't have to worry about it unless you have an IIFE (a self-executing function) that needs jQuery. Just make sure to wrap your module function calls in the jQuery closure.

```
$(function(){
     (function($){ $('body').append('<div />'); })(jQuery); // this needs the DOM & jQuery
});
(function(){
     my_module = my_module || {};
     my_module.nonjQueryFunc = function(){};
     my_module.myjQueryFunc = function(el){
         $(el).text("I need a ready DOM");
     };
});
```

In another .js file:

```
$(function(){
    my_module.myjQueryFunc(); // this needs the DOM to be ready & jQuery to exist
});

my_module.nonjQueryFunc();
```